# Android Java : Call method of an activity in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've three activities, A,B and C.

1. In activity A I've two functions that get sales data from firebase which I'm displaying in a recycler view.
2. User can search for products in Activity A, the search results are shown in Activity B.
3. Selecting a Product in Activity B opens the Activity C where user can purchase a product.
4. At this point, I want to call the two functions of Activity A from Activity C to update the data in Activity A for the recycler View.
   Which leads to my original question, How do I get Activity A's method in Activity C. Or if there's a better way to do this please guide this newbie, Thanks.

**update**

Seems like some people misunderstood, so just wanna clarify a couple things.

1. I cannot use fragments in this particular reason although that would be a pretty easy solution.
2. Secondly, Everything is working fine, I was just curious if I could update the data in Activity A by adding the data in Activity C locally without needing to get it from firebase everytime. But thanks for the downvotes lol

Comment: all of your problems are resolved by just using a single activity with fragments

Comment: I already have 4 fragments in activity A in a bottom navigation view, and more, at this point the design is too complicated for me to add any more fragments, therefore i just want to keep it simple with just activities for now. Ps adding more fragments was resulting in an exception that I could not find a solution for anywhere so I shifted to just activities.

Comment: i don't really see/understand how your code is more complicated because of fragments, but ok

Comment: I agree with @a_local_nobody using a view model with fragments is the way to go. Google recommends using a single activity for your app and then adding fragments on top of the activity, this will allow for different layouts for larger screens. If the design is too complicated I would suggest finding a way to make it less complicated so the app is maintainable. If its too complicated and you are working on it imagine how hard its going to be working 6 months done the road when you want to add a new feature.

Comment: @a_local_nobody  Thanks guys, I get what you're saying. It's just that I'm doing this app for a school project, on a deadline and I'll never see this app again after a week. That still does not justify what I'm doing but at this point I just want to be done with it so I shifted from using fragments to doing it in activities as I was already nesting 3 fragments and it was leading to some wierd exceptions. Anyhow, for anyone reading this at a later date, You should just do it with fragments instead of being like me.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're overcomplicating it.

When you purchase a product in Activity C, you should store the data on Firebase database. When you go back to Activity A you should obtain the list of purchased items from firebase and display them.

You cannot call methods of Activity A from Activity C. So don't be scared of obtaining data from Firebase every single time you open the activity, in the onCreate() method.

Comment: `You cannot call methods of Activity A from Activity C` really ? how sure are you about that ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody if you really try, you probably can. But to update the recycler view in an activity that doesn't have the view initialized, is not possible

Comment: Thanks, I'm already doing that. I was just curious if i could update the data in activity a by adding new sale data locally in activity c without fetching it again from firebase everytime.

Comment: @Jak you can store it in a ROOM database, or if you want an easier solution but less optimal for this scenario, you can use sharedPreferences. This will store the data locally on the android device.

Comment: @OskarLasota thanks, I'll give that a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a searchList and Add those search or selected items in searchList in Activity A and share that list with Activity B via parcelable Array List in intent.
From Activity A share your list by this,

```
ArrayList<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();
Intent intent = new Intent(Current.class, Transfer.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)object);
intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get that list in Activity B like this,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
ArrayList<Object> object = (ArrayList<Object>)args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
```

if you want to share that same list to Activity C then share that list again like we do in Activity A and get that list via bundle like Activity B.